# How to calculate previous n days mean using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate like previous 10 days' means for each day.

For example, in the result table, in column A, '1/11/2000' shows 44, which is the average of A values from '1/1/2000' to '1/10/2000'.

Raw Data:

```
              A      B       C
1/1/2000     60      62      88 
1/2/2000     46      99      28 
1/3/2000     20      23      94 
1/4/2000     28      19      79 
1/5/2000     58      45      12 
1/6/2000     50      46      62 
1/7/2000     68      4       55 
1/8/2000     54      64      79 
1/9/2000     26      41      63 
1/10/2000    33      10      18 
1/11/2000    37      82      73 
1/12/2000    67      33      29 
1/13/2000    2       82      17 
1/14/2000    82      74      51 
1/15/2000    9       46      81 
1/16/2000    72      84      70 
1/17/2000    74      77      100 
1/18/2000    19      88      37
```

Result:

```
               A      B      C
1/1/2000            
1/2/2000            
1/3/2000            
1/4/2000            
1/5/2000            
1/6/2000            
1/7/2000            
1/8/2000            
1/9/2000            
1/10/2000           
1/11/2000    44      41      58 
1/12/2000    42      43      56 
1/13/2000    44      37      56 
1/14/2000    42      43      49 
1/15/2000    48      48      46 
1/16/2000    43      48      53 
1/17/2000    45      52      54 
1/18/2000    46      59      58
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rolling.mean()` with a `shift`:

```
df.rolling(window = 10).mean().applymap(round).shift()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Warning/Caveat

`numpy` often (not always) provides more performant solutions.  However, they are also less intuitive and less flexible.  I'm offering this solution to provide useful information to the community.  I wouldn't recommend this to someone just getting familiar with `pandas` and `numpy`.  I suggest you read @Jeff's comments below as well.

## `numpy` using `as_strided`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as stride

v = df.values
n, m = v.shape
s1, s2 = v.strides

# note that `np.nanmean` is used to address potential nan values
pd.DataFrame(
    np.nanmean(stride(v, (n - 9, 10, m), (s1, s1, s2)), 1).round(),
    df.index[9:], df.columns
)

              A     B     C
1/10/2000  44.0  41.0  58.0
1/11/2000  42.0  43.0  56.0
1/12/2000  44.0  37.0  56.0
1/13/2000  42.0  43.0  49.0
1/14/2000  48.0  48.0  46.0
1/15/2000  43.0  48.0  53.0
1/16/2000  45.0  52.0  54.0
1/17/2000  46.0  59.0  58.0
1/18/2000  42.0  62.0  54.0
```

---

***time test***
[image]

Comment: with missing values this will fail: numpy is not friendly for things like this

Comment: @Jeff It was an easy fix to use `np.nanmean` and accommodate nan values.  Please reconsider your down vote or give further commentary.  Thanks.

Comment: recommending people to use striding for this is just crazy. Sure there are advanced users whom occasionally can do fancy things but 99% people should never touch a numpy  soln like this. and it's quite inflexible. just try to skip 2 nans in a period.

Comment: @Jeff, I respect your opinion.  As such, I try to soak in whatever wisdom I can from you and others.  Do you believe it is better not provide an answer such as this at all.  Or to leave an answer such as this with appropriate caveats.  As of right now, I'm of the opinion that this is useful information.  Can I be more responsible and give a louder warning, if you suggested that I do so, I would.  But based on your comments, I'm thinking you'd rather not see this kind of answer at all.  What would you recommend I do that would be most appropriate for the community.

Comment: yes it's a useful answer, but always the caveat is that most users will not (and should not do this); he occasionally some numpy routines are more performant, but they are almost always less flexible and syntactically challenging. so with those caveats it is fine.